# Monitoring Agent for Sensu, Librato

Tags: monitoring, newrelic, sensu, agents, librato

Can we have a single agent/clients for following monitoring tools,

1. Sensu
2. Librato
3. Nagios
4. NewRelic

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so. Because each tool works based on different architecture. For example, Nagios works only with below agents. These agents are required to be installed on client machines(Machines which are being monitored). And these agents are not supported by other listed tools.

1. NCPA
2. NRPE
3. NRDP
4. NSClient++

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a single agent for this use case as said by @Akie.
But you can integrate Sensu and Newrelic with **Grafana**.

So, this will give you a single view for multiple dashboards in different application. You won't need to go on other applications and login everytime.

What is Grafana?

Dashboard - The open platform for beautiful 
analytics and monitoring.

For New Relic you can use a plugin in Grafana, but for Sensu you can follow many blogs online. Here is a good [example](https://blog.powerupcloud.com/step-by-step-install-and-configure-sensu-grafana-9cedca333396?gi=d0c2f4ab0a11).